# Creating oracle sequence through hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, oracle12c

I am trying to create a sequence in Oracle, I am using Spring boot which have hibernate by default. I am having full priveleges to create and drop sequences.
But everytime I get an exception:`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist`

```
@GeneratedValue(generator="data_cat", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=1, initialValue=100, name="data_cat", sequenceName="BLAH_SCH.DATA_CAT")
@Id
private long id;
```

Following is my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

I believe it should create by upon any call to database. Please tell me what could be wrong.

However when I run sql commant in oracle my sequence gets created.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "BLAH_SCH"."DATA_CAT";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but :

Could you try to define the initial value in your Oracle sequence like  `CREATE SEQUENCE DATA_CAT START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was a space. Yes a space was there after this property

"spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create "

Once I checked the logs I came to know that this property was not getting picked. Removing this space made it work.